# How to integrate Disqus in my Android App?

Tags: android, comments, disqus

I am developing an android app for a web-site. The web-site supports Disqus for commenting  service. I want to support the same in my application. I got APIs from Disqus docs but still I am not clear how to integrate them in my application. Please help me understand the implementation. Is anyone integrated Disqus comment service into their Android App?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into the same problem with having my web site disqus threads linked up with my android app. I wrote a little walkthrough if you are interested I will link to my walkthrough below. Basically in your android app you want to use a WebView and use a separate php file that can take your disqus identifier.

http://globeotter.com/blog/disqus-android-code/

Answer (score 5):

Thanks ndgreen. Seeing your idea I created a something different without a PHP file necesity:
https://gist.github.com/bichotll/5563926

This script just create the html from a simple function and load th.

Comment: Shouldn't this have been a comment? :/

Comment: My apologies, I think that you are right. Anyway, I couldn't write a comment for my reputation.

Comment: @bichotll I implemented the code that went up but I'm running into this error: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL data:text/html;null,%3Cdiv%20id='disqus_thread'%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cscript%20type='text/javascript'%3Evar%20disqus_identifier%20=%20'null';var%20disqus_shortname%20=%20'jebalog';%20(function()%20{%20var%20dsq%20=%20document.createElement('script');%20dsq.type%20=%20'text/javascript';%20dsq.async%20=%20true;dsq.src%20=%20'http://'%20+%20disqus_shortname%20+%20'.disqus.com/embed.js';(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]%20||%20do` ...

Comment: Maybe something about permissions? From time ago that I don't touch this code.

Comment: I am getting this error on running this: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.", source: http://a.disquscdn.com/embed.js (2)
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :
Google Login is working.
I did not tested Facebook yet.

```
static void setupDisqus(Context context, WebView disqus) {
    try {
        String URL = ""; // URL must be unique like identifier! Because Disqus, is using the url instead of identifier.
        String identifier = "";
        String shortName = "";
        String commentsUri = "https://captainsp.github.io/disqus_comments_dark_gray.html?" + "shortname=" + shortName +
                "&url=" + URLEncoder.encode(URL, "UTF-8") +
                "&title=" + URLEncoder.encode("Comments", "UTF-8") +
                "&identifier=" + URLEncoder.encode(identifier, "UTF-8");

        /*
         * You can use this colors in my Github Account:
         * disqus_comments_dark_gray.html
         * disqus_comments.html
         * disqus_comments_dark.html
         *
         *
         */

        disqus.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(disqus::reload, 2000); // Reload Comments
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            }
        });
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(disqus, true); // Accept Cookies to login (If you forget this part users need to login every single time)
        disqus.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true); // Google / Facebook Login
        disqus.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true); // Google / Facebook Login
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true); // Accept Cookies to login 2
        disqus.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
                WebView newWebView = new WebView(context); // Create new WebView
                WebSettings webSettings = newWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webSettings.setUserAgentString(webSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("; wv", "")); // Hide WebView User Agent
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context); // Create Dialog
                dialog.setContentView(newWebView);
                dialog.show();
                CookieManager.getInstance().acceptThirdPartyCookies(newWebView);
                newWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                newWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
                        dialog.dismiss(); // Close the dialog after logged in
                    }
                });

                ((WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj).setWebView(newWebView);
                resultMsg.sendToTarget();

                return true;
            }
        });
        disqus.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript
        disqus.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        disqus.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        disqus.loadUrl(commentsUri);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

First create a new WebView or find it with `findViewById(R.id.webView);`
Then setup Disqus to your WebView: `setupDisqus(this,webView);`

More information : https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717165-javascript-embed-in-native-apps